# How to call function from arm assembly?(segmentation fault)

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm

I want to call `team`, and output data

It shows `segmentation fault`

Here's my code:

C program:

```
int main(){
  team();
  return 0;
}
```

```
void team(){
  printf( "abc\n" );
  printf( "def\n" );
  return;
}
```

Arm assembly language:

main.s

```
  .data
  .text
  .globl main
main:
  stmfd sp!,{lr}
  bl team
  ldmfd sp!,{lr}
  mov pc, lr
  .end
```

team.s

```
      .data
number1: asciz "abc"
number2: asciz "def"
     .text
     .globl team
team: stmfd sp!,{lr}
      ldr r0,=number1
      ldr r0,[r0]
      ldr r1,=number2
      ldr r1,[r1]
      bl printf
      ldmfd sp!,{lr}
exit: mov pc,lr
```

output:

```
abc
def
```

Comment: Do you know how `printf` works? You forgot to pass a format string. Also, you load a word when you want to load a byte.

Comment: @Jester I don't know a little bit how ```printf``` works. How can I do pass a format string?  and I need to add a few characters, such as ```asciz "abcd"```? Sorry for lots of problems.

Comment: See [man 3 printf](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) or any C documentation. It's unclear what you want to achieve, but if it is to print two characters you might want `"%c %c"` as format string and use `ldrb r0, [r0]` instead of `ldr` to load. Note: format string goes into `r0` so your two characters go into `r1` and `r2` then.

Comment: @Jester I updated some information. Hope you can understand what I want to do

Comment: To do the same thing in asm, you'd need two printf calls just the same. Also, you do not need to dereference. So, `ldr r0, =number1; bl printf; ldr r0, =number2; bl printf`

Comment: @Jester Thx. But I have a question. Why need to use ```ldr r0,=number2``` instead of ```ldr r1,=number2```?

Comment: Because the first argument goes into `r0`. You have two calls to `printf`, each with a single argument. So it's `r0` for both calls. How would `printf` know to fetch the value from `r0` first time around, but `r1` the second time? It uses `r0` always.